# Implementing a custom cross-platform userspace filesystem with WebDAV instead of FUSE

Tags: filesystems, webdav, fuse

Implementing a custom filesystem that works in userspace cross-platform seems like a daunting task - FUSE is great on linux, but awkward to install on OSX, and Windows doesn't support userspace filesystems at all. (One workaround discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/179436/is-it-possible-to-use-fuse-with-windows) for Windows is to run a linux VM with FUSE and Samba, and then use SMB to mount the FUSE filesystem on Windows.

But most platforms come with a WebDAV filesystem built-in, and building a cross-platform WebDAV server seems pretty easy. So this seems like a straightforward way to implement a userspace filesystem, but I haven't seen it done before.

My question: What filesystem features might be impossible or impractical to implement through a WebDAV server?

Here's what I can see so far:

*Things a WebDAV server can't do that a FUSE filesystem can:*

- Files can have creation and modification dates, and of course sizes, but can't have individual users, groups, and permissions. There is an RFC for ACLs over WebDAV, but it's [not widely supported by WebDAV clients](http://sabre.io/dav/acl/). (On my mac, all files seem to appear as user readable, writable, and executable, and owned by me.)
- According to the WebDAV protocol, files can have arbitrary metadata, but the WebDAV filesystems available do not (to my knowledge) expose any of that metadata. (However, I can serve .DS_Store, thumbs.db, or desktop.ini files to get some platform-specific behavior.)
- Every file will appear as a "normal" file or a directory - symlinks, for example, are impossible.

Any other limitations?